# How to send url from template to view in django

Tags: python, django

How can I send a URL from a template to a view? I have noticed that a normal string works but a URL doesn't. Here is what I have tried.

```
path('imageviewer/<str:theimage>', mainviews.imageviewer, name="imageviewer"),
    
def imageviewer(request, theimage):
    response = render(request, "imageviewer.html", {"theimage": theimage})
    return response
```

How I attempt to pass it : (value.image) is a url

```
<a href="{% url 'imageviewer' theimage=value.image %}" class="effect-lily tm-post-link tm-pt-60">
```

Error I Get:

```
Reverse for 'imageviewer' with keyword arguments '{'theimage': 'https://storage.googleapis.com/katakata-cb1db.appspot.com/images/humours/1643758561'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['imageviewer/(?P<theimage>[^/]+)\\Z']
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the image so that it can be used in a URL, use the built-in filter [`urlencode`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#urlencode)

```
    {% url 'imageviewer' theimage=value.image|urlencode %}
```

Your urlpattern also needs to accept slashes and other chars, use the `path` [converter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) instead of `str` as it accepts any non-empty string

```
path('imageviewer/<path:theimage>', mainviews.imageviewer, name="imageviewer"),
```

Comment: have tried it but it doesn't seem to work

Comment: @user13662507 Try `path` instead of `str` in your url pattern?

Comment: Thank you. path works even without encoding.

Comment: @IainShelvington Checked Django [urlize](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#urlize). Is there a way to display the resultant link as a **button**? Thanks.